# Deterministic API call results in the redux store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I have a deterministic API call to calculate IncomeTax which always returns the same values when supplied with a particular input.

Is it better practise to put the result of this API call in the redux store or should I use a caching library like redux-reselect.

Answer (score 1):

This is almost the perfect use-case for a selector library such as [reselect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reselect).

You should retrieve your calculated value via a selector getter that takes the input values. This will call api and cache the result based on the input values and, if those values change, the api will fetch the new value and cache it too.

If you use react then you should make sure you store your inputs in redux-state. That way should the state values be changed then the getter will be automatically called and the new (or previously cached) calculated value retrieved.

Comment: Thank you. Is it a good practise to make ajax calls from inside a selector?

Comment: No, definitely not. A selector should be synchronous, and simply return new values based on its inputs.